# Getting codeigniter error - A PHP Error was encountered Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

**CONTROLLER FUNCTION CODE:**

```
$surveydata = $this->getsurveydatabasedonId($SurveyId);
$this->load->view('editsurvey', array('surveydata' => $surveydata));
```

**VIEW CODE:**

```
   <h1 class="page-header">Edit Survey</h1>
                <?php
                $att = array('id' => 'editsurvey_form', 'role' => 'ajax-form');
                echo form_open('welcome/editsurvey', $att);
                ?>
                <div class="span5 offset1" id="form_div">
                    <?php echo validation_errors('<div class="alert alert-danger reg_error">', '</div>'); ?>
                    <div class="form-group control-group warning">
                        <input name="SurveyId" style="display:none" type="text" class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a Survey Id" id="SurveyId" required placeholder="Please enter the Survey Id" value="<?php echo set_value('SurveyId', $surveydata->SurveyId); ?>">
                        <label for="SurveyTitle">Survey Title</label>
                        <input name="SurveyTitle" type="text" class="form-control" data-validation-required-message="Please enter a Survey Title" id="SurveyTitle" required placeholder="Please enter the Survey Title" value="<?php echo set_value('SurveyTitle', $surveydata->SurveyTitle); ?>">
                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group control-group warning">
                        <label for="SurveyIntroduction">Survey introduction</label>
                        <textarea name="SurveyIntro" type="text" class="form-control" id="SurveyIntro" placeholder="Enter the Survey Introduction"><?php echo set_value('SurveyIntro', $surveydata->SurveyIntro); ?></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-warning">Edit Survey</button>
                </div>
                </form>
```

I am getting the following errors :

```
 A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/editsurvey.php

Line Number: 11
```

I am passing the array but it isn't working could someone help me please?

Comment: Is `$surveydata` contains the key `surveydata` in it in the controller ?

Comment: yes it does have put up the controller code as well

Comment: Can you check `var_dump($surveydata);` on top of your view file ?\

Comment: array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'SurveyId' => string '145' (length=3)
      'SurveyTitle' => string 'Survey 6' (length=8)
      'SurveyIntro' => string 'Survey 6' (length=8)
      'CreatedBy' => string 'm123456789' (length=10)
      'DateCreated' => string '2014-04-04 04:08:12' (length=19)
      'isDisabled' => string '0' (length=1)
      'SurveyLink' => string '21491' (length=5)

Comment: Access it using `$surveydata[0]['SurveyTitle']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make sure,

You have data in your `$surveydata`.

If you are fetching results through

`$resultSet->result()`  OR `$resultSet->row()`, then use `$surveydata->SurveyTitle`

And if you are fetching the results through:

`$resultSet->result_array()`  OR `$resultSet->row_array()`, then use `$surveydata['SurveyTitle]`

Also, please make sure to check count of `$surveydata`

Comment: This is the data array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'SurveyId' => string '145' (length=3)
      'SurveyTitle' => string 'Survey 6' (length=8)
      'SurveyIntro' => string 'Survey 6' (length=8)
      'CreatedBy' => string 'm123456789' (length=10)
      'DateCreated' => string '2014-04-04 04:08:12' (length=19)
      'isDisabled' => string '0' (length=1)
      'SurveyLink' => string '21491' (length=5)

Comment: I am fetching a row of data

Comment: Then, you should check num_rows().

Comment: Got it working thanks so much There was an issue with the row

Answer (score 1):

It should be `$surveydata[0]['SurveyId']`, not `$surveydata->SurveyId`

Same for SurveyTitle
It should be `$surveydata[0]['SurveyTitle']`, not `$surveydata->SurveyTitle`

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\wamp\www\surveytool\application\views\editsurvey.php on line 12 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0006264992{main}( )..\index.php:0 20.0017322600require_once( 'C:\wamp\www\surveytool\system\core\CodeIgniter.php' \

Comment: same mistake you have done on next line also. Please correct wherever you have used `$surveydata->SurveyId`

Comment: In controller what is the output when you do

`print_r($surveydata);`

Comment: when i do var_dump i get this array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'SurveyId' => string '145' (length=3)
      'SurveyTitle' => string 'Survey 6' (length=8)
      'SurveyIntro' => string 'Survey 6' (length=8)
      'CreatedBy' => string 'm123456789' (length=10)
      'DateCreated' => string '2014-04-04 04:08:12' (length=19)
      'isDisabled' => string '0' (length=1)
      'SurveyLink' => string '21491' (length=5)

Comment: Now check what happens?

Comment: yup solved the issue i got the row through  $data = $query->row(); and then it worked